# Trouble with a basic Java program's logic/condition loop/code

Tags: java, loops

I need to interpret a java program for a certain type of employee. There is some logic I do not understand in the setWage method..

```
public void setWage(double wagePerPiece)
{
 wage = ( wagePerPiece < 0.0 ) ? 0.0 : wagePerPiece;
}
```

I do not understand the way this conditional statement was typed up. Is this some type of shorthand for a type of loop? If so, I would understand it more if it was expanded in that form of loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is a conditional operator. The first part of it is a condition, and the second and third part are results based on that condition.

If `wagePerPiece` is less than 0.0, then it is executed as `wage = 0.0`, while if that is not the case, `wage = wagePerPiece` is run.

The basic structure is:

```
condition ? trueResult : falseResult
```

When the line is evaluated, first the condition is evaluated, and then if if is true, then the expression for `trueResult` is evaluated and used as the value of this expression. If it is false, then the `falseResult` expression is evaluated and that value is used as this complete expression.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the ternary operator. It is a shorter way of saying

```
public void setWage(double wagePerPiece)
{
  if(wagePerPiece < 0.0) {
    wage = 0.0;
  } else {
    wage = wagePerPiece;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment (really stupid Stack Overflow) on David's answer, it's the same as

```
public void setWage(double wagePerPiece) {
    double wage;
    if (wagePerPiece < 0.0)
        wage = 0.0;
    else
        wage = wagePerPiece;
}
```

Note that I put in his missing variable declaration.  Long story short, everything left of the ? is the conditional clause (the 'if').  Everything between the ? and the : is what happens if the conditional clause is `true`.  Everything after the : is what happens if the conditional clause is `false`.  Note that this is an if/else.  To do an if/else if/else with this shorthand is ugly, confusing, and very much not appreciated by your fellow developers :-)